# Python is not recognizing text file that is in the same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path, reddit, praw

My current project tree:

```
redditbot/  

-- commands/  
----__init__.py  
----comment_cache.txt  
----readcomments.py  

--mainbot.py
```

What I am attempting to do is read the comment_cache.txt file via `open('comment_cache.txt')`in the readcomments.py file., but for some reason I am getting a FileNotFoundError. Even when I try `print(os.path.isfile('comment_cache.txt'))`, it just returns false.

Am I making a beginner mistake here? Maybe something that just I keep missing?

EDIT: I appreciate all the answers/comments, but I believe it is a problem with my Python interpreter itself. I kept moving around the file between the redditbot/ directory and the commands/ package until it just started working. Also for some reason whenever I call `print()`, PyCharm tells me that it is undefined...

Comment: And you run this how? `open()` with a a relative path is relative to the current directory of the process of the Python interpreter (i.e. `os.getwcd()`), not relative to the directory the current module file is in.

Comment: Per your tree, it should be `commands/comment_cache.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that `mainbot.py` is the entry point from where you run your application, so

**Problem I**

based on your project tree, the file should be available at path

```
open('commands/comment_cache.txt')
```

**Problem II**

> I kept moving around the file between the redditbot/ directory and the commands/ package until it just started working.

You probably ended up placing the file in the same folder as your `mainbot.py`

**Problem III**

> Also for some reason whenever I call print(), PyCharm tells me that it is undefined...

There can be many posibilities behind this, check if the python interpreter is configured correctly and the python libraries are available on the PYTHONPATH for the project